# Update boolean in SQL Alchemy (using CRUD)

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, boolean, crud, traceback

I am trying to update the boolean statement from the default `False` to `True`. The idea here is that a user watches some video and the update method changes from `False` to `True`.

I am struggling with writing the `update_view_state` method. I have tried dot notation (I am admittedly new to this) and have been unsuccessful.

Using `Python 2.7` `SQLALCHEMY` and `CRUD method`

```
class View_State(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'view_states'
    #more code
    completed = Column(Boolean, default=False) #have to set default

    def __init__(self, user, video):
        self.completed = False
```

Update code:

```
def update_view_state(self, username, videoname, completed):
    #update Boolean completed status to 'complete = True'
    update_view = self.session.query(View_State).\
    filter(View_State.user.has(username == username)).\
    filter(View_State.video.has(videoname == videoname)).one()
    if update_view:
        print 'update view found: ', update_view.completed
        update_view.completed.append(completed)
        self.session.commit()
        return update_view
```

Test.py

```
api.update_view_state('ack', 'module1', True)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/enotss_copy/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 296, in test_crud_operations
    api.update_view_state('ack', 'module1', True)
  File "/Users/ack/code/enotss_copy/NotssDB/notssdb/api/convenience.py", line 35, in update_view_state
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).update_view_state(user, video, completed)
  File "/Users/ack/code/enotss_copy/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 634, in update_view_state
    filter(View_State.user.has(username == username)).\
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 442, in has
    return self.operate(PropComparator.has_op, criterion, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 383, in has_op
    return a.has(b, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1172, in has
    return self._criterion_exists(criterion, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1081, in _criterion_exists
    criterion = criterion._annotate(
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_annotate'
```

---

**with ANSWER from below:**

traceback:

```
ERROR: notssdb.test.test.test_crud_operations
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/enotss_copy/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 295, in test_crud_operations
    api.update_view_state('ack', 'module1', True)
  File "/Users/ack/code/enotss_copy/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 628, in update_view_state
    filter(View_State.user.has(username == username)).\
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 442, in has
    return self.operate(PropComparator.has_op, criterion, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 383, in has_op
    return a.has(b, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1172, in has
    return self._criterion_exists(criterion, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1081, in _criterion_exists
    criterion = criterion._annotate(
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_annotate'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to `append` to `update_view.completed`.  It's a boolean, not a list, right?

Comment: @coralv how do you update the boolean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment, I think it's better I just post an answer to provide the detail.  Hopefully this helps you get it cleared up and running properly.

```
def update_view_state(self, username, videoname, completed):
    #update Boolean completed status to 'complete = True'
    update_view = self.session.query(View_State).\
    filter(View_State.user.has(username == username)).\
    filter(View_State.video.has(videoname == videoname)).one()
    if update_view:
        print 'update view found: ', update_view.completed
        update_view.completed = True # Simply reassign it like a variable
        self.session.add(update_view) # Add it to the session
        self.session.commit() # And commit
        return update_view
```

I've used `self.session` in the code, because that's what you're using.  I've never set up my sessions that way, so I've only ever used `session.commit()` or `session.add()`, but I'm trying to stay consistent with what you've got posted, as that may be required by some other, unposted, part of your code.

I've directly updated to the boolean `True` here, but I see that you've taken in a function paremeter `completed` that you may prefer to use.  In that case, simply use `update_view.completed = completed`.  Perhaps consider renaming that parameter to avoid confusion with the column in your database bearing the same name.

As you asked, if we rename the parameter `completed` to `status_change` it would look like this:

```
def update_view_state(self, username, videoname, status_change):
    #update Boolean completed status to 'complete = True'
    update_view = self.session.query(View_State).\
    filter(View_State.user.has(username == username)).\
    filter(View_State.video.has(videoname == videoname)).one()
    if update_view:
        print 'update view found: ', update_view.completed
        update_view.completed = status_change # Simply reassign it like a variable
        self.session.add(update_view) # Add it to the session
        self.session.commit() # And commit
        return update_view
```

In this case, you would be able to use the function to set `update_view.completed` to either `True` or `False` if you wanted to switch back and forth.  Doing so would just be a matter of passing the Boolean of your choice in as an argument to the function.  If you only ever want to set it to `True` using this function, then you could remove the `status_change` parameter entirely, and use the raw Boolean value as in the first example.

Comment: if you were to rename it, say `status_change` as the variable to avoid confusion, what would that look like in the code above?

Comment: I'm getting a traceback. SEE ABOVE^

Comment: Found the issue. I needed to do a join for the query since I am using the user and video objects. This answer is now applicable! I will add the working query above.

Comment: Glad you found the issue and got it working!  I'll edit my answer to include changing `completed` to `status_change` so you can see how that looks.